# Exercise in bash on processes

Tags: bash

I'm practicing in bash but i'm having huge problem in this exercise, can you help me?

This is the exercise:

> Make a shell script that will list all users with a number of processes less than root and %mem greater than at least a root process. For each user of this kind the script will create a file .txt where you list PID, PPID,% MEM of such processes

Sadly my attempt doesn't work at all, it reports a problem at row 7 "ps: awaiting integer expression".

```
#! /bin/bash

N_root=$(ps hax -o user | sort | uniq -c | grep root | awk '{print $1}')     # here I save how many processes root has
mem_root=$(ps -u root -o %mem | sort | head -1)                                # I save the lowest %mem of root
for i in $(ps hax -o user | sort | uniq -c | sed '/root/d')             # listing all processes
do
    if [ $(echo $i | awk '{print $1}') -lt $N_root ]                     # i check if this user has less processes than root
    then
        user=$(echo $i | awk '{print $2}')                         # i save the name of the user
        if [ $(ps -u $user -o %mem | sort -r | head -1) -gt $mem_root ]   # check if the max %mem is greather than the lowest %mem of root
        then
            echo $user
            touch <$user>.txt                                  # creating file "<user>.txt"
            for p in $(ps -u $user -o %mem,pid,ppid | sed '/PID/d' | sort -r)  # listing all processis of current user ($n)
            do
                if [ $(echo $p | awk '{print $1}') -gt $mem_root ]             # check if the process has more %mem than root
                then
                    echo $p >> "<$user>.txt"                           # copying %mem,pid,ppid in the file
                fi
            done
        fi
    fi
done
```

Comment: Please, add a copy of your script and the error in the post and choose a meaningful title.

Comment: the script checking the difference of the **memory use** not the CPU... so, here is some difference what you need and what you doing...

Comment: Take a look at http://www.shellcheck.net/

Comment: Your script does not take an input parameter. Please choose better variable names: r, m, n, u, i -- not meaningful

Comment: Do you get a line number error? Maybe something pointing us to the problem? Have you put `set -xv` at the top of your script. This will produce a line-by-line execution output of each command. You can use that info to help locate where the problem could be.

Comment: "doesn't work" and "reports problems" are useless for us: *what* problems? what do you expect to happen and what actually happens?

Comment: @jm666 I'm sorry, i posted a wrong description

Comment: @glennjackman Sorry, the description was wrong, I edited the post but i think there're a lot of problems with my attempt, the only one i can see by running it is that it detects an error in row 7 about ps command, i wrote it in the post.

Comment: Hint: run your script as `bash -x your_script_name` and will see, where isn't working. Especially check the `for i in $(ps hax -o user | sort | uniq -c | sed '/root/d')` line.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of ways to approach this. For multi-comparisons, I generally like to index the values into arrays and then perform the comparison with a single loop through the values (if possible). Applied to your problem, it might look like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

## set output filename
ofn=./userpctmem.txt

## arrays to hold procs, users, and %mem
declare -a procarray
declare -a userarray
declare -a memarray

## read values into arrays
while read -r pval uval || [ -n "$uval" ]; do
    procarray+=( "$pval" )
    userarray+=( "$uval" )
    memarray+=( $(ps -u "$uval" -o %mem | grep -v '%' | sort -r | head -n 1) )
done <<<"$(ps hax -o user | sort | uniq -c)"

## save root procs and %mem in separate variables for convenience
rproc=$(ps -u root | tail -n +2 | wc -l)
rmem=$(ps -u root -o %mem | grep -v '%' | sort -r | head -n 1)

## get the number of users found
nusers=${#userarray[@]}

## print the captured data (for verification)
printf "\n%-12s  %-6s  %s\n\n" "user" "nprocs" "maxmem"
for ((i=0; i<$nusers; i++)); do
    printf " %-12s %5s   %s \n" "${userarray[i]}" "${procarray[i]}" "${memarray[i]}"
done

## test user process less than root and %mem >= root (max %mem process)
#  and write matching users to output
printf "\nUsers with nprocs less than root and %%mem at least as great as root\n\n"
for ((i=0; i<$nusers; i++)); do
    [ "${userarray[i]}" == 'root' ] && continue
    umem="${memarray[i]}"
    if [ "${umem//.*/}" -ge "${rmem//.*/}" -a "${procarray[i]}" -lt "$rproc" ]; then
        printf " %s has process with %%mem: %s, root %%mem: %s\n" "${userarray[i]}" "$umem" "$rmem" | tee -a "$ofn"
    fi
done

printf "\n"

exit 0
```

**output:**

```
alchemy:~/scr/tmp/stack> bash procmem.sh

user          nprocs  maxmem

 avahi            1   0.0
 david           68   18.7
 man              2   0.0
 messagebus       1   0.0
 nscd             1   0.0
 ntp              1   0.0
 polkitd          1   0.5
 postfix          2   0.0
 root           105   2.8

Users with nprocs less than root and %mem at least as great as root

 david has process with %mem: 18.7, root %mem:  2.8
```

**output file:**

```
alchemy:~/scr/tmp/stack> cat userpctmem.txt
 david has process with %mem: 18.7, root %mem:  2.8
```

**note:** retrieving the PID and PPID for the process with max %MEM is left for an exercise. If you have difficulty after trying, drop a comment and I'll show you a way to capture it.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help! But, unfortunately, in our course we didn't study any data structure in Bash, so arrays are out of range for me at this moment.
I still thank you for the time you put in helping me.